# How to redirect to another view in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-dom

Im developing an app where I need to login and after click tha Login button I need to redirect to another view that is in another layout, I've tried using **this.props.history.push("/Inicio")** to redirect when the Login is succesful. In this case this is the path.

```
{
path: "/Inicio",
name: "Inicio",
component: Inicio,
layout: "/admin"
},
```

This is the entire code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
   Grid,
   Col
} from "react-bootstrap";

import { Card } from "components/Card/Card.jsx";
import { FormInputs } from "components/FormInputs/FormInputs.jsx";
import Button from "components/CustomButton/CustomButton.jsx";

class Login extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      users: [],
      user: '',
      pass: '',
      msg: '',
      apiResponse:''
  }
  this.logChange = this.logChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var data = {
    user: this.state.user,
    pass: this.state.pass,
    msg: this.state.msg,
    apiResponse: this.state.apiResponse
  }
  console.log(data)
  fetch("http://localhost:9000/log/Login", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error("Bad response from server");
      }
      return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    if(data == "success"){
      console.log(data) 
      this.setState({users: data});
      this.props.history.push("/Inicio");
      window.location.reload();
    }
    else{
      if(data == 'El usuario o la contraseña no coinciden'){
        this.setState({ apiResponse: data })
      }
      
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
  });
  }
  logChange(e) {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});

  }

render() {
return (
  <div className="content">
    <p class="col-md-4"></p>
    <Grid >
        <Col md={5}>
          <Card
          
            title="Login"
            content={
              <form method='POST' onSubmit= {this.handleSubmit}>
                <p class="col-md-2"></p>
                <FormInputs
                  ncols={["col-md-7"]}
                  properties={[
                    {
                      label: "Usuario",
                      type: "text",
                      bsClass: "form-control",
                      placeholder: "Usuario",
                      maxlength: 20 ,
                      name: "user",
                      onChange: this.logChange
                    }
                  ]}
                />
                <p class="col-md-2"></p>
                <FormInputs
                  ncols={["col-md-7"]}
                  properties={[
                    {
                      label: "Contraseña",
                      type: "password",
                      bsClass: "form-control",
                      placeholder: "Contraseña",
                      maxlength: 20,
                      name: "pass",
                      onChange: this.logChange
                    }
                  ]}
                />
                <p >{this.state.apiResponse}</p>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <Button bsStyle="info" pullRight fill type="submit">
                  Login
                </Button>
                <Button bsStyle="info" pullLeft fill type="submit">
                  Olvide mi Contraseña
                </Button>
                
                
              </form>
            }
          />
        </Col>
    </Grid>
    
 </div>
);
}
}

export default Login;
```

but in the **handleSubmit()** everything is working fine except for **this.props.history.push("/Inicio")** because it doesn't do anything.

The index.js code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./assets/css/animate.min.css";
import "./assets/sass/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss?v=1.3.0";
import "./assets/css/demo.css";
import "./assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";
import LoginLayout from "layouts/LoginLayout.jsx";
import EfoodLayout from "layouts/EFoodLayout.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/login" render={props => <LoginLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/Efood" render={props => <EfoodLayout {...props} />} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/login/Login" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

LoginLayout

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import LoginNavbar from "components/Navbars/LoginNavbar";
import Footer from "components/Footer/Footer";


import routes from "routes.js";

class Login extends Component {

getRoutes = routes => {
return routes.map((prop, key) => {
  if (prop.layout === "/login") {
    return (
      <Route
        path={prop.layout + prop.path}
        render={props => (
          <prop.component
            {...props}
            handleClick={this.handleNotificationClick}
          />
        )}
        key={key}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
};
getBrandText = path => {
return "Bienvenido a E Food";
};

render() {
 return (
   <div className="wrapper">
      <LoginNavbar 
        brandText={this.getBrandText(this.props.location.pathname)}
        
      />
      <Switch>{this.getRoutes(routes)}</Switch>
      <Footer />
      
   </div>
  );
 }
} 

export default Login;
```

I hope you can help me, and thanks to everyone who answer.
**PD: If you need more from my code, please let me know.**

Comment: Is the component in question being rendered within a `Router` by a `Route` in order for it to receive the route props, or decorated with the `withRouter` HOC? Can you update with entire component code, and what your Routing looks like?

Comment: In the meantime, it appears as though you may not have properly bound `this` of the class to `handleSubmit`. Your assigned `this` to a variable `self` and when you try to still use `this` when just above it `self` was used to update state. Saving `this` to a variable `self` isn't really a pattern you need to use in react though. If you can update your question with entire component and router code we'll have a better idea what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I said bellow, Im new using react, and I've retrieved all my frontend from a template that I've found on Internet, I have edited it to look like I wanted, so I don't really know how exactly it works in deeply, I have an idea of what the component is, but I dont really know if it is what im thinking, and the same with the router, If you dont mind I could send you the entire code via GitHub or another way, only if you accept of course I dont want to bother you.

Comment: If you could just post the relevant code in your question that would be great, but a link to your repo is better than nothing. Links to code generally aren't recommended as that content can change, move, or be deleted and the question then will be missing context.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I've edited the post with the entire code of the question and the index.js, i hope this can help, if not, I will post my repo link here, of course when you have accessed the link, i will delete it to avoid problems.

Comment: Oh, sorry, links as supplemental information are 100% ok, just not as the primary source. Will check this out. So I see the router renders `LoginLayout` and is passed all the route props. Can we see also `LoginLayout` to see if/how it passes props to children, presumably `Login`?

Comment: I have placed the loginlayout in the question and I reviewed the Documentation of the routing system of the template too, and it says this: Because our routes are arrays of objects, and each route is an object, you can add what props you want in our routes and do what you want with them.

For example, if you want to "hide" a route (you want it to not be displayed in sidebar), you could add a prop like invisible: true and then in sidebar add an if statement inside the map function of ours and do like this:
if(prop.invisible) return null;  Maybe this could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since it's obvious the component you want to do the navigation in is a deeply nested component there are a couple options.

## Prop Drilling (not recommended)

[prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling)

The cons of prop drilling is that if the right props aren't passed to begin with, or if *any* component along the way forgets to pass on props, then some child component won't receive what they need and it may be difficult to track down the what or why it's missing. It's more difficult to maintain as now any changes to *this* component necessitate needing to be concerned about every other component around it. Prop drilling is *actually* a react anti-pattern.

LoginLayout

Your `LoginLayout` component appears to consume a routes config object and dynamically render routes. It needs to pass on the route props it received from its parent. Any component between here and the `Login` where you want to use `history.push` would need to keep passing all the props down.

```
class Login extends Component {
  getRoutes = routes => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.layout === "/login") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            render={props => (
              <prop.component
                {...props}
                {...this.props} // <-- Pass on all props passed to this component
                handleClick={this.handleNotificationClick}
              />
            )}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
  
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

## Use `withRouter` Higher Order Component (recommended)

[withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

> You can get access to the **`history`** object’s properties and the closest
> `<Route>`'s `match` via the withRouter higher-order component. `withRouter`
> will pass updated `match`, `location`, and **`history`** props to the wrapped
> component whenever it renders.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; // <-- import HOC
import { Grid, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

import { Card } from "components/Card/Card.jsx";
import { FormInputs } from "components/FormInputs/FormInputs.jsx";
import Button from "components/CustomButton/CustomButton.jsx";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      user: this.state.user,
      pass: this.state.pass,
      msg: this.state.msg,
      apiResponse: this.state.apiResponse
    };
    console.log(data);
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/log/Login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (data == "success") {
          console.log(data);
          this.setState({ users: data });
          this.props.history.push("/Inicio"); // <-- history prop should now exist
          window.location.reload();
        } else {
          if (data == "El usuario o la contraseña no coinciden") {
            this.setState({ apiResponse: data });
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  logChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login); // <-- decorate Login with HOC
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `react-router-dom` to handle your routing ? If so, you can use [the hooks to navigate](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks).

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
...
const history = useHistory()

...
history.push('/Inicio')
```

Note that this will only work with React version >= 16.8

The reason why your code is not working is because of the bindings.

When using `this.props.history.push("/Inicio")`, `this` refers to the function you're in, not to the Component history.

If you want to keep your code that way, you can simply turn your function into an arrow function:

```
  .then((data) => {
      if(data == "success"){
        console.log(data) 
        self.setState({users: data});
        **this.props.history.push("/Inicio")** // now this will be correct
        **window.location.reload();** // no need, react handles the reload
      }
      else{
        if(data == 'El usuario o la contraseña no coinciden'){
          self.setState({ apiResponse: data })
        }
        
      }
```

Although, I'd strongly advise using the latest features of react (check the hooks, it's really useful).

Comment: React hooks.... functional components. OP is clearly using a class-based component.

Comment: @DrewReese Which is why I also answered using his own code, but still suggested him to swap to functional components

Comment: That's like taking your Brand X car to the mechanic to fix it and the mechanic says, "Well, I drive a Brand Y and it works, so you should drive a Brand Y too." It doesn't explain why OP's code isn't working as expected and doesn't begin to resolve it. You may be on to something with the function bindings though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you tell me where can i see the react version, to be honest Im new using react, and I retrieve all my front end from a template, so I don't really know my react version.

Comment: I already have tried with '''import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
...
const history = useHistory()

...
history.push('/Inicio')''' but it tells me this error ***Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.***

Comment: @FranHerrera you're not using the correct version of react-router-dom :) Make sure you're using the latest one. And good luck on your way up, react is an amazing library !

Comment: @PierreOlivierTran I have noticed that, I have never used it before and it is very easy to learn, and thank you a lot!

Comment: @FranHerrera and again, I know that functional components seem a bit odd at first, but I cannot stress enough how easier it is to write clean code once you master it. Take a look at react-router documentation, you'll be up and running in no time !